# Problems with a two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, html

[the image shows my idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY9dY.png) and
that's what I have till now -->

The main idea behind the JS code is creating HTML view of matrix 5x5 like it is given on an image. Unfortunately, my numbers overwrite themselves.
How can I fix it?

```js
function numberMatrix() {
var items = [
  [1, 3, 3, 3, 3],
  [2, 1, 3, 3, 3],
  [2, 2, 1, 3, 3],
  [2, 2, 2, 1, 3],
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 1]

];
var y = 0;
var par = document.getElementById('it');
while ( y < 5 ) {
  for  (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    par.innerHTML = items[y][i]; 
  }
    par.innerHTML = '<br>';
  y++;
}
}

numberMatrix();
```

```css
#it {
    border: 1px solid green;
    font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>

</head>

<body>
    <p id="it"></p>
    
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `+=' instead of '='

```
while ( y < 5 ) {
    for  (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        par.innerHTML += items[y][i]; 
    }
    par.innerHTML += '<br>';
    y++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `par` never changes, and you keep changing what it is equal to.

Instead try using `+=` to append information

```js
function numberMatrix() {
  var items = [
    [1, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    [2, 1, 3, 3, 3],
    [2, 2, 1, 3, 3],
    [2, 2, 2, 1, 3],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 1]

  ];
  var y = 0;
  var par = document.getElementById('it');
  while (y < 5) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      par.innerHTML += items[y][i];
    }
    par.innerHTML += '<br>';
    y++;
  }
}

numberMatrix();
```

```css
#it {
  border: 1px solid green;
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <p id="it"></p>

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only one element `par` which you are not updating. So everytime it is overwriting the old one. It would be better if you use `<div>` instead of '

' in html code and generate and add '

' from javascript code same as you added '
' at the end.

New html code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="it"></div>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

New javascript code :

```
function numberMatrix() {
var items = [
  [1, 3, 3, 3, 3],
  [2, 1, 3, 3, 3],
  [2, 2, 1, 3, 3],
  [2, 2, 2, 1, 3],
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 1]

];
var y = 0;
var par = document.getElementById('it');
while ( y < 5 ) {
  par.innerHTML = '<p>'
  for  (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    par.innerHTML = items[y][i]; 
  }
  par.innerHTML = '</p><br>';
  y++;
}
}

numberMatrix();
```